# why do Non-English words not saved correctly in SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arabic, collation

I am working with `MSSQL server 2008R2` , I have a field of type `nvarchar(255)` I had changed its collation to `Arabic_100_CI_AS` but the field is still showing **'???'** instead of `Arabic` words.

I tried to restart the Server after collation changed but it did not work !

NOTE : Old collation was `Latin`

**NOOTE** I am inserting directly from The DB , If I write a query the problem raise, if I edit the table directly , there is no problem and the arabic words are displaying correctly !

What should be done ?

Thanks

Comment: is the table in tempdb??

Comment: Did you try to insert new data and check if the problem is exists on old data or both old and new data?

Comment: HI all ,Thanks for the reply , YES i tried to insert new data but same problem.

Comment: The table is not in tempdb , it in a DB i have created.

Comment: Looks like a UI problem to me.

Comment: The font you use for the client is unicode and support the arabic letters?

Comment: I am inserting directly from The DB , If I write a query the problem raise, if I edit the table directly , there is no problem and the arabic words are displaying correctly !

Comment: An `nvarchar` column can store arabic characters regardless of collation. The collation is only for comparison and sorting. If you don't see the arabic characters you probably inserted them from a non-unicode source

Comment: Are you inserting data via a client connection or directly from Management Studio? If using a client make sure it passes arabic characters to DB, i.e. the client should support Unicode characters.

Comment: Hi adrianm
 
I am inserting the data directly from the SQL server using normal queries !

Comment: Do you prefix the string with `N` i.e. `N'<arabic characters>'`

Comment: Thank you adrianm , prefixing N solved the problem , thank you\

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adrianm the solution was prefixing the text with N

such as : N'MyArabicText'

Thanks all for cooperation..